# Preciso modificar a ação tomada ao fechar um JFrame

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, java-8, jframe, persistência

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com persistência em Java para um trabalho de faculdade, e preciso que o sistema salve automaticamente os dados ao fechar a aplicação (com uma função pronta fornecida pelo professor).

A minha pergunta é a seguinte: há uma forma de eliminar o botão de fechar padrão criado pelo NetBeans, ou modificar a ação tomada ao clicar no botão?

Desde já agradeço.

[Link da aplicação](https://github.com/arthursiq5/CrepeMaker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sim tem como, no netBeans a maneira mais pratica é clicar com o botao direito em cima do seu jframe e ir em propriedades.. na primeira linha ja vai ter um defaulCloseOperation... tem 4 opções.. também outra idéia é criar um evento que salve sua aplicação antes de fechar literalmente o programa.. isso você pode fazer por exemplo clicando no seu frame com o botão direito>>Eventos>>Window>>windowClosing>>

esse evento sera chamado no encerramento da janela..